# scala sortBy using _ placeholder parameter does not work

Tags: scala

In Scala, List(3,2,1,5,2,4).sortBy(x => x) works,

but if you replace with List(3,2,1,5,2,4).sortBy(_), it doesn't work.

I understand _ is placeholder parameter. Why doesn't it work in this case?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

sortBy() takes a function as parameter. `x => x` is a function, but just `_` , in this case is interpreted as converting sortBy from a method to a function.

In the general case, if you dislike writing `x => x`, you can use the `identity` function (e.g, you can write `.sortBy(identity)` ).

In the case of sortBy() however, it would be imo nicer looking to just write `List(3,2,1,5,2,4).sorted` to achieve the same thing.

Comment: I edited, feel free to do it when you see something wrong :-)

Answer (score 1):

A single underscore by itself is not interpreted as a placeholder. In this case, it would instead be interpreted as converting `sortBy` from a method to a function. If you want an alternative to `x => x`, use `identity`: it may not be shorter, but it is more readable. As C4stor points out, `List(3,2,1,5,2,4).sorted` also works in this case.